# why don't my global variable get any value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I declare a global variable (var arrDatas = []) as an array in order that it can get value from the response of $.get method but it don't has any value.

The response from servlet will be "name1,abc@email.com;name2,def@email.com;name3,ghj@email.com;....."

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arrDatas = [];

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#lecturerName').autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {
                    var value = $('#lecturerName').val();
                    $.get('getLecturer', {
                        keyWordLN : value
                    }, function(responseText) {
                        **arrDatas = responseText.split(";");**
                        var arrName = [];
                        for ( var i = 0; i < arrDatas.length; i++) {
                            tem = [];
                            tem = arrDatas[i].split(",");
                            arrName[i] = tem[0];
                        }
                        response(arrName);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $.fn.pressEnter = function(fn) {

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).bind('enterPress', fn);
                $(this).keyup(function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        $(this).trigger("enterPress");
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#lecturerName').pressEnter(function() {
                name = $('#lecturerName').val();
                email = "Chua lay duoc email";
                for ( var i = 0; i < arrDatas.length; i++) {
                if (arrDatas[i].indexOf(name) > 6) {
                    tem = [];
                    tem = arrDatas[i].split(",");
                    email = tem[1];
                    }
                }
                var $ulList = $('#selectedEmails');
                value = '<li><div class="vT">'+ name+ '</div><div class="vM"></div><input type="hidden" name="txtToEmail" value="'+email+'"></li>';
$('<li>').text(value).appendTo($ulList);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And my jsp page :

```
<tr>
            <td>Người nhận</td>
            <td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="lecturerName" size="26">
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="menu-bar">
                    <li><a href="1">Home</a>
                        <ul id="selectedEmails">
                            <li>
                                <div class="vT">Name</div>
                                <div class="vM"></div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="txtToEmail" value="email">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My servlet :

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String key = request.getParameter("keyWordLN");

            Connection cnn = XJdbc.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT Name, Emails FROM lecturers WHERE Name LIKE '%"+key+"%'";
            Statement stm = cnn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            String result = "";
            while (rs.next()) {
                result = result + rs.getString("Name") + "," + rs.getString("Emails")+";";
            }

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().print(result);
            cnn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me know that why my global variable "arrDatas" don't have any value.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why don't you edit your servlet to return JSON and simply use `JSON.parse()` to create an object?

Comment: `console.log(responseText);` and `console.log(typeof responseText)`, what's the result of both? Also please note that your global array might still be empty if you are trying to access it from anywhere outside your `$.get` callback since of the asychronous nature of Ajax.

Comment: could you give me an example how to use JSON in this case ?

Comment: @plalx : 
the result of console.log(responseText) is : name Of User one,username1@gmail.com;name Of User two,username2@gmail.com;name Of User three,username3@gmail.com;
and the type is string

Comment: @user2971216 Ok, so where in the code are you trying to access the array and it's empty?

Comment: @plalx : arrDatas = responseText.split(";");

Comment: @user2971216 That is not possible if what you told me before holds true. Try `console.log(responseText.split(';'));` and I am sure it will be an array of emails.

Comment: @plalx it's main arrDatas=console.log(responseText.split(';'));

Comment: @user2971216 What? No... do `arrDatas = responseText.split(';'); console.log(arrDatas);` You get an array of emails right?

Comment: @plalx: i've known my mistake, thank you a lot :D
by the way, may i ask you a question :D
do you know any tag which will convert text to html ? :D